# Python script to Python UDF

Tags: python, hive, apache-pig, udf

I have python script - which reads data from hive table, format it using pandas and writes the updated data back to a new hive table.
Can I convert this normal python script(which contains raw script & other functions too) to a python udf?
If yes, can I access hive from the udf too ?

Thanks in advance